# Not Displaying The map and the multiple markers

Tags: php, javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i trying to display many markers on google map.all works fine in too cases

1. i display ONE marker
2. i write the GPS localisations of different markers

i have a data base which contains Longitude,latitude values
i want to dispaly those values as markers on my map

here is a try but is not working,plz help me i spend all day already :/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>multi-marqueurs</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
          type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
<? php

$connexion=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("project",$connexion) or die(mysql_error());


$result = mysql_query("SELECT lattitude,longitude FROM intervenantconn ");


$listeDesPoints='';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  if($listeDesPoints!='') $listeDesPoints.=','; 
  $listeDesPoints.='['.$row['lattitude'].','.$row['longitude'].']';
}

mysql_close($connexion);
?>
  <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 550px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">

var listedespoints=[
                      <? php  echo $listeDesPoints; ?>
                    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 6,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.4,1.6),
          mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    },
    navigationControl: true,
     navigationControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
    },
        scaleControl: true,
    streetViewControl: false,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

   for (i = 0; i < liste_des_points.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(liste_des_points[i][1], liste_des_points[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you notice that you are trying to loop liste_des_points instead of listedespoints? plus are you viewing your javascript console? that should give you some errors? :)

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <   :////

Comment: show `var_dump($listeDesPoints);` before mysql_close($connexion);

Comment: i sorry im j2ee studient, is that mean i put an echo var_dump($listeDesPoints); ?

Comment: yes and show me the results `var_dump($listeDesPoints);` will be enough

Comment: there is nothing showing up.. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <  on this ligne var liste_des_points=[
<?php echo $listeDesPoints; ?>]; it seems that ths page html is not traiting the php code ://

Comment: in your example code you have spaces between <? and php this should be  `<?php` without space

Comment: im sorry Bass Jobsen , i deleted the space but same issue.. im going to suicide but really thx for ur patience Bass

Comment: replace `mysql_close($connexion);` in your code with `var_dump($listeDesPoints); mysql_close($connexion); exit;` and show the results

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < caused by var listedespoints=[<?php  echo $listeDesPoints; ?>
                    ]; ( i hope see another error --')

Comment: that's a javascript error cause by the output of `echo $listeDesPoints;`. That's why i think `$listeDesPoints` don't have the right format.

Comment: what should i do plz?

Comment: show the results of var_dump or look in the source code of your html to find what echo $listeDesPoints; prints

Comment: this seems to be the right string. fix the Notice from line 16

Comment: im sorry ..i put the php in other file ( externel fil not included in html) and i did what u told me to do i get string '[20,21],[20.454856,21.548]' (length=26)
[20,21],[20.454856,21.548] ( values in my data base) thank god and thank you

Answer (score 0):

1) As @mauno-v told you use `liste_des_points` instead of `listedespoints` to loop.

2) In your loop you use the secnd and third entry `liste_des_points[i][1], liste_des_points[i][2]` while you only create two entries.

3) in you click event you use `locations[i][0]` where locations is not defined.

So create a list with three entries `['location name','latitude','longitude']` or change your indices and variable names.

See below:

```
<?
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting','on');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>multi-marqueurs</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
          type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
<?php

/*$connexion=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("project",$connexion) or die(mysql_error());


$result = mysql_query("SELECT lattitude,longitude FROM intervenantconn ");


$listeDesPoints='';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  if($listeDesPoints!='') $listeDesPoints.=','; 
  $listeDesPoints.='['.$row['lattitude'].','.$row['longitude'].']';
}
mysql_close($connexion);*/

$listeDesPoints='[\'Location 1\',47.45,2],[\'Location 2\',47.46,1.6],[\'Location 2\',47.47,1]';
?>
  <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 550px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">

var liste_des_points=[
                      <?php  echo $listeDesPoints; ?>
                    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 6,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.4,1.6),
          mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    },
    navigationControl: true,
     navigationControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
    },
        scaleControl: true,
    streetViewControl: false,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

   for (i = 0; i < liste_des_points.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(liste_des_points[i][1], liste_des_points[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(liste_des_points[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: still "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < "

Comment: for statics location it works i can get all markers..but from mysql table :/ takes me all day :'(..i change all things u told me to change ( the loop, a static list)